# What does `Client.findById(id)` mean?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Looking through the Play documentation for Java I noticed the following block of code:

```
public static Result show(Long id) {
  Client client = Client.findById(id);
  return ok(views.html.Client.show(client));
}
```

Source: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaRouting

I am having some trouble understanding the second line, my understanding of Java Object creation is a typical constructor looks like the following:

```
Person john = new Person();
```

What is the second line doing?  Creating a Object called client from Class called Client, also what is Client?  It doesn't appear to be a part of the Play Framework, certainly I cannot find anything in JavaDocs.

Thanks

**Edit:**

I found this to be a good point of reference for the answer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Also I think the class Client comes from the following documentation (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1.1/controllers) with Client being just a example model class, the new documentation probably needs updating to clear up this confusion.

Comment: Questions of type: "I found some code over here, I'm having trouble understanding line X" is a discussion type question and is should not be upvoted.  Imagine if stackoverflow only contained these sorts of questions.  It would no longer be a top 100 site.

Comment: @EricLeschinski I disagree. There's no discussion to be done here. It's not all that complicated of a question to a seasoned Java developer, but for someone new to Java it is completely reasonable.

Comment: Certainly there is diminishing return for novices to post very complex lines of code and asking: "What does line 5 mean"?  Too much of that, and people will stop coming to stack overflow for relevant answers.  My gut instinct is to ask: "Well, what have you tried?  What do you think it means?"  We can't answer his question unless we know just how much of a novice he is.  Should we link to an explanation on variables or about Instantiation?  It's a discussion on how to interpret code.  An interesting problem, but too large to fit into a question/answer format.

Comment: I think Ben's answer was pretty clear, I don't see how it's a discussion, I have edited my initial post to include the relevant section from official Java documentation just to be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty clearly, the class `Client` has a static function of `findById`, which takes a `Long` and returns a `Client`.  Static functions are functions that are defined without any access to object properties, and therefore can be accessed through the class name, rather than having to be accessed through an object.  Most likely, the class has a static property containing a collection of all clients in the system by index, and `findById` grabs an existing `Client` from that list.

I really have no idea where the class `Client` is defined, however.  I've also made a quick look around for it, and couldn't find it in the obvious places.

Comment: @ Ben Barden - Thank you very much, your concise explanation has cleared up my confusion, my only follow up question would be - say there is a Client object with the id of 3, does the object initialization in line 2 create a new object called "client" with exactly the same attributes as the returned object i.e. id of 3, thus a duplicate?

Comment: I do not have access to the findById code, and thus cannot say with certainty, but my suspicion based on general usage would be that it would return a reference to the original object, rather than cloning it.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a `static` method called `show(Client)` on the `views.html.Client` class that returns some object. That object is passed into an `ok(whatever)` method, and that `ok` method returns a `Result` object.

Comment: Thanks also for your comment, however my confusion was surrounding the second line, sorry if that wasn't clear in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some basic knowledge/experience. The sample you gave has nothing to do with `routes` and in this snippet only first line is important, second is just some *hypothetical* usage. De facto it could be just...

```
public static Result show(Long id) {
  return ok("You want to display details of client with ID: " + id);
}
```

Although @BenBarden explained what is that mean correctly , this static method **isn't** declared anywhere, it's (again) hyphotetical usage of some ORM. For an example the real usage with Ebean's model will be:

```
Client = Client.find.byId(id);
```

Of course you can also declare own method in your `Client` model and name it the same as in the sample, however it will be just only wrapper:

```
public static Finder<Long, Client> find
        = new Finder<>(Long.class, Client.class);

public Client findById(Long id) {
    return find.byId(id);
}
```

#### Conclusions

- You need to examine some samples available with your Play sources to get familiar with some basic syntax, fortunately you'll find it easy.
- **DO NOT MIX** documentation from Play 1.x with Play 2.x they are **not** compatible!